# Background doesn't work when I run the app on my phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, background

I am currently making a new app and I have a very weird problem that I have never experienced before.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="555dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background1" >
```

You can see the XML code for main activity above and the problem is that when I run the activity on my phone I can't see the background1. However if I click the gaphical layout, I can see the background and everything works normally. Only when I compile and run on my android phone the activity is blank, without the background, just white.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the parent view which is `ScrollView`,
You simply need to add `android:fillViewport="true"` so change the layout to:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="555dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background1" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly, it still won't work. I tried creating a new activity without the scrollview, a simple blank activity and also set its background and the error si the same. I don't get why this is happening, in every other app this works perfectly.

Comment: EDIT: I even tried it on virtual device now (completely forgot to do that earlier before posting question...no idea what's with my head lately) and it even works there...it only doesn't show the background when I run it on the phone.

Comment: Try to change "@drawable/background1" to color and see if it will work.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks, your answer didn't help me directly but it did put me on the right path to figure out the answer :) My background was transparent, that's why this was happening. Thank you!

Comment: @Whiz I'd really appreciate if you describe the solution step by step since I am straggling with the same problem, can't see the bg on my Nexus 5 device, how do I resolve this transparency issue? What should I change?

I could only solve it by copying the image to the other drawable directories. Any advice?

Comment: @AYBABTU I am very, very sorry but I have absolutely no idea how I solved this. It's been 2 years since I had this problem and I really can't remember what it was about. I hope you find your solution.